# How can i make sidebar panel dynamic in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

```
**#Ui.code:**

library(shiny)
fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=h2(" Lucas Tvs",align="center")),
  sidebarPanel(



   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Profit Loss'",
selectInput("Operations","Select the desired Profit Loss statement",choices = profitloss1$Operations)),

br(),

   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Profit Loss'",
          selectInput("summary1","Select the desired Summary",choices = summary1$OPERATIONS)), 

 conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Ratio'",
      selectInput("Ratio","Select the desired Ratios",choices=ratios1$Ratios)),
 br(),
 conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Ratio'",
                  selectInput("summary","Select the desired Summary",choices = summary$RATIO)),


 conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Balancesheet'",
    selectInput("Particulars","Select the desired Balancesheet statement", choices = Balancesheet$Particulars)),

 br(),

    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Balancesheet'",
      selectInput("summary2","Select the desired Summary",choices = summary2$PARTICULARS))

 ),


    mainPanel(

    tabsetPanel(id="tabs1", 

   tabPanel("Profit Loss",column(5,tableOutput("profitloss")), column(7,plotOutput("plot")),tableOutput("summary1")),
   tabPanel("Ratio",column(5,tableOutput("Ratio")),column(7,plotOutput("plot2")),tableOutput("summary")),
   tabPanel("Balancesheet",column(5,tableOutput("Balancesheet")),column(6,plotOutput("plot1")),tableOutput("summary2"))

    )      


)
)
```

In the UI part I have created 3 tabs in the main panel and 2 select inputs in the sidebar panel.All those are reacting dynamically but now I want my code to show me that both the select input in the side bar panel are mutually dependent on each other.
    **#server code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input,output){

    output$profitloss<-renderTable({
      oporationfilter<-profitloss1[profitloss1$Operations==input$Operations,c("Years","Value")]

    })
    output$Ratio<-renderTable({
      ratiofilter<-ratios1[ratios1$Ratios==input$Ratio,c("Years","Value")]
    })

    output$Balancesheet<-renderTable({
      Balancesheetfilter<-Balancesheet[Balancesheet$Particulars==input$Particulars,c("Years","Value")]
    })

   output$summary<-renderTable({
     summaryfilter<-summary[summary$RATIO==input$summary,c("Mean","Standard.Deviation","CAGR.1","CAGR.3","CAGR.5")]
   })
   output$summary1<-renderTable({
     summary1filter<-summary1[summary1$OPERATIONS==input$summary1,c("Mean","Standard.Deviation","CAGR.1","CAGR.3","CAGR.5","CAGR.7")]
   })

   output$summary2<-renderTable({
  summary2filter<-summary2[summary2$PARTICULARS==input$summary2,c("Mean","Standard.Deviation","CAGR.1","CAGR.3","CAGR.5")]
   })



    output$plot<-renderPlot({
      options(scipen = 999)
      p<-ggplot(data = profitloss1[profitloss1$Operations==input$Operations,]
                ,aes(x=Years,y=Value))
      p+geom_line()+xlab("Years")+ylab("Value in Lakhs")+ggtitle("Profitloss Plot")
     })


    output$plot2<-renderPlot({
      q<-ggplot(data = ratios1[ratios1$Ratios==input$Ratio,]
                ,aes(x=Years,y=Value))
      q+geom_line()+xlab("Years")+ylab("value in lakhs")+ggtitle("Ratios Plot ")
    })

    output$plot1<-renderPlot({
      q<-ggplot(data = Balancesheet[Balancesheet$Particulars==input$Particulars,]
                ,aes(x=Years,y=Value))
      q+geom_line()+xlab("Years")+ylab("value in lakhs")+ggtitle("Balancesheet Plot")
    })
  })
```

This is the code for designing of the website now I want my both the select input should be mutually dependent.
for example: If select in XXX in drop down menu I should automatically get the same output in the 2nd select input.

Comment: Please edit your question to display the code and text properly.

Comment: and make a reproductible example, cuz that code is not able to run.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  I have  updated my code and requirement  too.